# dialogframgent width

Tags: android, dialogfragment

I am using dialogFragment to make my own custom fragment but its size does not look like what is in priview
this is what is showing in preview

[image]

and this what happens when the dialog is shown

[image]

I want it to look exactly like my preview - what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext, R.style.Theme_Transparent);

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                           .inflate(R.layout.layout_custom_dialog, null);
    dialog.setContentView(view);

    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
    wlp.width = wlp.MATCH_PARENT;
    wlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    wlp.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND;
    window.setAttributes(wlp);
```

And add this to `styles.xml` file

```
    <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    </style>
```